# React native Wix Navigation.push possible unhandled promise rejection: Error : Failed to execute stack command

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

React native Wix Navigation.push  possible unhandled promise rejection: Error : Failed to execute stack command

Login.js

```
signUpLink =(screenName) => {


          Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: screenName,
  }
});


    }

 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonText}   onPress={this.signUpLink('videostreme.SignUpScreen')}>
                <Text style={styles.signUpText} >First time here?? Sign Up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

index.js

```
Navigation.registerComponent('videostreme.LoginScreen', () => Login);
Navigation.registerComponent('videostreme.MainScreen', () => Main);
Navigation.registerComponent('videostreme.SignUpScreen', () => SignUp);
Navigation.registerComponent('videostreme.SplashScreen', () => Splash);

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
     stack: {
         children: [
         {
             component: {
                 name: 'videostreme.MainScreen'
             }
         },

         ]
     }
    }
  })
})
```

How to handle this promise (Navigation.push), anyone have idea about this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working when I gave *componentId* directly instead of *this.props.componentId* (this is undefined when I console it). So I directly give componentId,

```
redirectPageHandler = screenName => {
  Navigation.push('login', {
   component: {
      name: screenName
   }
  });
}
```

The reason why *this.props.componentId* is undefined is, we need to pass the props from parent component.

My child component is **Login** and parent component is **App**

**App.js**

```
render() {
  return (
   <Login {...this.props} />
  )
}
```

Now, we can use *this.props.componentId* in the child component

**Login.js**

```
redirectPageHandler = screenName => {
  Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
   component: {
      name: screenName
   }
  });
}
```